# « C'est pas tout ça »

Tags: expressions

Que que signifie cette expression? Quand l'utilise-t-on? Un exemple d'utilisation est fourni par la [troisième citation](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/victuaille) illustrant le mot *victuailles*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

L'expression « c'est pas tout ça » est très couramment utilisée dans le même sens que « Bref. » : elle apparaît généralement pour clore un sujet dans la discussion courante et revenir à un autre sujet, souvent abordé plus tôt dans la discussion, et qui se trouve généralement être de plus grande importance que le sujet précédent l'expression.

Le but est généralement de montrer à l'interlocuteur qu'on souhaite clore la discussion en cours pour commencer ou reprendre autre chose de plus important.

> « C'est pas tout ça, mais j'ai un rendez-vous urgent ! »

Answer (score 4):

"C'est pas tout ça" sert de formule "passe partout" pour se sortir d'une discussion/situation dans laquelle on ne souhaite pas rester, pour y mettre fin avec politesse.

Exemples : "c'est pas tout ça mais je dois y aller", "c'est pas tout ça mais j'ai du travail qui m'attend"

C'est une expression plutôt familière.

Answer (score 1):

Finalement "c'est pas tout ça" est assez grossier, car vous interrompez brutalement une conversation en la qualifiant de "tout ça" et signifiez que vous devez prendre congé rapidement.

Il vaut mieux dire "Excusez-moi, je dois partir" ou bien, un peu plus ampoulé "Je vous prie de m'excuser, il faut absolument que je parte".